# How to Align the Namesection to the left, to add a passport size image on right?

Tags: fancyhdr, deedy-resume

I am new to LaTeX, using Overleaf to compose my new CV.

My question is that i would like to add a passport size photo to the right end of the namesection (i.e. right top corner of the document), so i would like to be able to left-align the name and email address line in a way that the space occupied by the photo be considered as part of the right margin for this section and the document looks even.

Right now it is with the original alignment, meaning that the white space on the right side of name & email address lines is same as the white space on the left side.

P.S: I'm attaching the start of the latex code, to give you some insights about the template and style I'm using:

```
\documentclass[]{deedy-resume-openfont}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
 
\begin{document}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%     TITLE NAME
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\namesection{RAM}{SHARMA}{ 
\urlstyle{same}\href{https://github.com/ramXYZ}{GitHub} |href{mailto:ramXYZ@gmail.com}{ramXYZ@gmail.com} | (+91)8tabcdef9}

 %This is the section(name and email) which  want to move to the left, so that I can add my image.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. It's generally  more helpful to post a complete minimal document rather than just a fragment of code. And since this is an all volunteer operation, adding things like "URGENT" isn't usually received very well.

Answer (score 0):

You could adapt the code below to your liking--date can be inserted as per choice

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}%<------------only for check, remove for finals

\author{RAM SHARMA \\mailto:ramXYZ@gmail.com \\ramXYZ@gmail.com}
\title{\textbf{XXX YYYY ZZZZ}}


\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\date{}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}\noindent
    \begin{tabular}{C{11cm}L{3.5cm}}
        {\maketitle} & \raisebox{-3\baselineskip}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth] 
        {example-image-a}} 
    \end{tabular}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: The  OP is using a totally different document class: `deedy-resume` so this isn't really an answer to the question.

Comment: Exactly. I tried what he had written above, but it isn't solving my problem.Maybe, he missed on something in my question and code snippet.

Comment: i forgot the documentclass--where is it available this deedyresume

Comment: Not sure about the answer to your query @js bibra. I found this template on overleaf, and hence used it.

Answer (score 0):

For this I used the [Deedy CV template on Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/deedy-cv/bjryvfsjdyxz). By default, the name section layout is centred:

[image]

Add

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

to the document preamble, and then use the following setup for your `\namesection` instead of the default:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%     TITLE NAME
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\namesection{Debarghya}{Das}{ \urlstyle{same}\href{http://debarghyadas.com}{debarghyadas.com}| \href{http://fb.co/dd}{fb.co/dd}\\
%\href{mailto:deedy@fb.com}{deedy@fb.com} | 607.379.5733 | \href{mailto:dd367@cornell.edu}{dd367@cornell.edu}
%}
% Retrieve definition of \namesection from .cls and update
% Left named section
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}%
  {%
    \fontsize{40pt}{60pt}%
    \fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Hai}\selectfont Debarghya 
    \fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Lig}\selectfont Das
  }\\[5pt]
  {%
    \color{headings}
    \fontspec[Path = fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-Medium}\fontsize{11pt}{14pt}\selectfont
    \urlstyle{same}\href{http://debarghyadas.com}{debarghyadas.com}| \href{http://fb.co/dd}{fb.co/dd}\\
    \href{mailto:deedy@fb.com}{deedy@fb.com} | 607.379.5733 | \href{mailto:dd367@cornell.edu}{dd367@cornell.edu}%
  }
\end{minipage}%
% Right passport section
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
  \raggedleft
  \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+30pt}{\includegraphics[height=65pt]{sample-image.png}}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{5pt}
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\color{headings}\rule{\paperwidth}{0.4pt}}

\vspace{-5pt}
```

The idea is to set two `minipage`s side-by-side, with the left holding the named content and the right holding the image.

[image]